# React: Always Keep the first four characters onchange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So basically I have an input component for phone numbers. I am using the react native phone input library, so the international code is added by default. I want to set the input change in such a way that the international code `+234` never gets deleted with the back button. I believe regex is the way to go using `let regex = /[^+234]/g` to match the start but I don't know how to proceed next.

So basically if a user types any number in, `+234` is added by default to the beginning of phoneNumber. With the current design of the library, the `+234` prefix gets deleted when the user deletes the number . What I want is for the `+234` to be kept no matter how much the user deletes

CODE

```
 const onChangePhoneNumberHandler = (phoneNumber: string) => {
        setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
        showMessage({ text: ``});
        
    }

    <PhoneInput 
         value={phoneNumber}
        onChangePhoneNumber={onChangePhoneNumberHandler}
    />
```

Comment: You can do whatever you want with phoneNumber before you call setPhoneNumber

Answer (score 0):

```
const onChangePhoneNumberHandler = (phoneNumber?: string) => {
    const newNumber = phoneNumber?.includes("+234") ? phoneNumber : "+234"
    setPhoneNumber(newNumber)
    showMessage({ text: ``});
    
}
```

Might wanna fine tune the logic part but that is a quick solutin